# Giving an item in a list a new value using Razor

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to give my `ComponentID` a new value when iterating through my list this is how I currently set it up

```
 @{Component subComp = db.Components.Find(Model.ComponentSubComps[c].ID);}
  @for (int sp = 0; sp < subComp.CHP.Count; sp++)
        {
             Part sPart = db.Parts.Find(Model.SubCompParts[sp].ID);
             @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.SubCompParts[sp].PartID)
             @Model.SubCompParts[sp].ComponentID == @subComp.ID;
        }
```

As you can see I try assigning the value by doing this

```
 @Model.SubCompParts[sp].ComponentID == @subComp.ID; 
//also tried this @Model.SubCompParts[sp].ComponentID = @subComp.ID;
```

But this isn't working. How can I properly assign the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two equal signs are equality, not assignment. Also, you are already inside a code block but are switching contexts when you call the `@Html.HiddenFor` method. Change this:

```
@Model.SubCompParts[sp].ComponentID == @subComp.ID;
```

To this:

```
@{ Model.SubCompParts[sp].ComponentID = subComp.ID; }
```

There are several other things worth noting in your code but I will refrain from commenting on those.

Comment: Thanks but I had tried both ways, when I change it to ```=``` I get this error **CS1525: Invalid expression term '='**

Comment: The correct answer was to change it so looked like this ```{ Model.SubCompParts[sp].ComponentID = subComp.ID; }``` the brackets were important. Thabks for your assistance!

Comment: @ryan Yes, that is what I posted. Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you. You are mixing code with Razor output. That and the two equal signs are your issue.

Comment: You added the brackets after I commented and there should be no ```@``` in front of the brackets either as it is already in a block. But I will mark it as accepted. Thanks!